# When i import the module in IPFS cluster using nest js like (import cluster from 'ipfs-cluster-api';) then i face the error

Tags: typescript, nestjs

Could not find a declaration file for module 'ipfs-cluster-api'. '/home/user/Documents/nest-code/node_modules/ipfs-cluster-api/src/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
Try `npm i --save-dev @types/ipfs-cluster-api` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'ipfs-cluster-api';

if I follow to install npm then also I see these error below:

npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@types%2Fipfs-cluster-api - Not found
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  '@types/ipfs-cluster-api@*' is not in this registry.
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/user/.npm/_logs/2022-10-17T05_18_23_277Z-debug-0.log

Answer (score 0):

The error message comes from the fact that Typescript is looking for type information about `ipfs-cluster-api` and not finding it, so the language server gives you two suggestions: install a `@types/` package for it (which as you found doesn't exist) or create your own types for it. To create your own types file for the library to get the error to go away, you should just need a `d.ts` file like

```js
declare namespace 'ipfs-cluster-api';
```

And now just import this `d.ts` file inside your `main.ts` and everything should be good

Comment: I have already gone through all the given process commited by you just now.  from all those given steps the error disappeared but moment i hit the api it suddenly appear

Comment: What error appeared? The Typescript error about not being able to find the types, or something else? That Typescript server error shouldn't be happening att runtime